# TypeError: story.test is not a function with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing  a program that increases a counter every time the user presses the space bar, as you can see i did it with regexp and i used test() to test the match. The problem is that every time i press the spacebar on the textarea i get an error 'TypeError: story.test is not a function'. What am i doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var counter = $('#counter').text();
  var story = $("textarea#story").val();
  var space = /\s/g;

  function count() {
    var n = 0;
    var testIt = story.test(space);
    if(testIt) {
      n++;
    }
    counter = n + ' Words';
  }

  $('textarea#story').keypress(function(key) {
    if(key.keyCode === 0 || key.keyCode === 32) {
      count();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: `.test()` is a method on `RegExp`, not `String`. It should be `story.match`

Comment: I believe it should be the other way round ie `space.test(story)`

Comment: Also, you're setting `story` to the contents of the text area when the page is loaded, you're not updating it when the user types. You should assign the variable inside the `count()` function.

Comment: thanks to all of you. it works